# ROS2 unable to locate package

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I'm using ROS2 humble in Ubuntu 22, and trying install MAVROS, but something goes wrong

I work according this doc https://docs.px4.io/main/en/ros/ros1.html

passing command via terminal

`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-mavros ros-kinetic-mavros-extras`

I've got this message

`Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-mavros E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-mavros-extras`

What the problem?

Answer (score 0):

got it!
I have to point out my ros distr for example:
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-mavros ros-humble-mavros-extras